# Good way to store settings for an XNA screensaver?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, settings, screensaver

What's the best way to store settings for a screensaver that happens to use XNA? i'm thinking of using a .settings file but i'm unsure how to read that from my XNA code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but over at Creators Club there's a sample that uses XML files to store settings for a particle system: [Authoring Particle Systems Using XML and the Content Pipeline](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/tutorial/particlexml). If you simply want to store some settings this might be a good fit for your problem.

Otherwise Nick Gravelyn has a post on [Storage Device Management](http://nickgravelyn.com/?p=751) in XNA.

Seeing as it's a screensaver though, you could just go ahead and import the System.IO and System.XML namespaces.